# Custom шрифт Android studio [API 27]

Tags: android, textview

Помогите найти ошибку:

Я скачал шрифт .ttf, создал папку asset (на ровне с res и java), создал там папку "fonts", засунул шрифт "11408.tff".

в XML TextView дал id, а в фрагменте, который запускается вместе с MainActivity, прописал в onCreate:

```
TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/11408.tff");
t.setTypeface(typeface);
```

где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заюзать шрифты в папке res/font

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

или

```
Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

[источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

Comment: Первый вариант не получился. Зато второй прошел сразу!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться следующим [примером](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12063076/5330439)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
       TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Zipcode);
       Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/customfont.ttf");
       txt.setTypeface(font); 
       return v;
}
```

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит, потому что код полностью похож на тот, что я дал. На всякий случай проверил - не подошло